# Usar variável de uma função em outra função

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma variável que tem o valor resultante de uma função, preciso usar esse mesmo valor em outra função.

Ex:

```
el1.on('change', function'){
    //função pra trazer o valor que quero
    var IdResult1 = 123 //valor que a função acima trouxe
    $('.meuLink').attr('href','?parametro1='+idResult1)});



el2.on('keyup', function'){
    //Outra função pra trazer outro valor
    var idResult2 = 456 //valor que a função acima trouxe
    $('.meuLink').attr('href','?parametro1='+idResult1+'&parametro2='+idResult2); // quero usar a variavel aqui
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Declare a variável **fora** das funções, num nível de escopo que seja comum às duas:

```
var IdResult1;
el1.on('change', function() {
    //função pra trazer o valor que quero
    IdResult1 = 123 //valor que a função acima trouxe
    $('.meuLink').attr('href','?parametro1='+idResult1)
});

el2.on('keyup', function() {
    //Outra função pra trazer outro valor
    var idResult2 = 456 //valor que a função acima trouxe
    $('.meuLink').attr('href','?parametro1='+idResult1+'&parametro2='+idResult2); // quero usar a variavel aqui
});
```

Para isso funcionar, o `keyup` do `el1` precisa ocorrer antes do outro, ou a variável estará sem valor definido quando ocorrer o `keyup` do `el2`.

Comment: Show de bola, funcionou mas o estranho que eu havia tentado antes usando var idResult1 = ""; não funcionou e deixando dessa forma funcionou :D Obrigado!

Comment: Tem de funcionar atribuindo um valor inicial também, contanto que seja fora da função.